# Is geth command line and mist Wallet UI console the same thing?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

In mist browser, I can open Develop | Toggle Developer Tools | Wallet UI and go to the console tab. I can type in all sorts of commands here that control the browser. For example, I can remove unneeded contracts from the watch contract screen with `CustomContracts().find().fetch()` and then remove.

Question: is the console command line in Mist the same command line I get when I start geth in a terminal window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those are 2 different things.

### Browser console.

> The Browser Console is like the Web Console, but applied to the whole browser rather than a single content tab.

[image: Opening the Browser Console]

### geth Console

> It is a terminal interface to interact with the `go-ethereum` utility.

[image]

*If you write javascript functions using `web3` to interact with a geth console, you can see the functions available in the Browser Console. Means you can invoke geth console from Browser Console.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The console in Mist is just the Javascript Console and allows you to do any functions that are in the Javascript of the Mist UI.

Geth command line tools are totally different.